# How can I update the state so that my page gets reloaded automatically and I don't have to reload manually?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I don't know how to update the state so that my page reloads automatically. Every time I am reloading manually to see the change in quantity of the perfume. I am new in this field please help me if anyone can solve it.

```
const Inventory = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [perfumeDetail] = usePerfumeDetail(id);
    const [perfumeQuantity, setPerfumeQuantity] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/perfume/${id}`;
        fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setPerfumeQuantity(data));
    }, []);


    const handleDeliveredQuantity = id => {
    const oldQuantity = parseInt(perfumeQuantity.quantity);
    const quantity = oldQuantity - 1;

    const perfume = { quantity };


    const url = `http://localhost:5000/perfume/${id}`;
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(perfume)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        alert('perfume delivered successfully!!')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have confirmation that the perfume was delivered successfully, you can update the state with the same object you sent to the backend:

```
const url = `http://localhost:5000/perfume/`; // since url is the same, you can declare it as a const and append the id when you use it

const Inventory = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [perfumeDetail] = usePerfumeDetail(id);
    const [perfumeQuantity, setPerfumeQuantity] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(url + id)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setPerfumeQuantity(data));
    }, []);

    const handleDeliveredQuantity = (id) => {
        const oldQuantity = parseInt(perfumeQuantity.quantity);
        const quantity = oldQuantity - 1;

        const perfume = { quantity };
        fetch(url + id, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(perfume),
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                alert('perfume delivered successfully!!');
                setPerfumeQuantity(perfume);  // updating the state here will update the value on the UI as per what you have sent in your PUT request
            });
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tired your code but it doesn't help. Still I have to manually reload the page to update the changes.

Comment: @SadiaTuzJohora What all changes are you expecting to take place? I there anything else other than quantity?

Comment: No, only the change in quantity. After clicking the "delete one" button the quantity should decrease by 1 every time. It is decreasing by one but I have to manually reload to page to see the change in quantity.